I can't get text view displayed on my phone, but I got text preview on android studio
Here is my first app code.......

I only see "Hello" on andriod preview
When I run the code my phone shows me it is already connected successfully, but there no textview.
On the top of my phone it only says "Hello Android!"
Please help me on this!!!!!!

i am not an expert of android java, but what you are showing is not a java code , but the xml layout view, which sounds to do what you asked it for. Then you need a piece of Java code to play with it. See [https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/declaring-layout#java]

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please do not post code or xml data as screenshot. Just copy and paste the text into your question and format it as code.

Check your Activity class, maybe this TextView has been set to "Hello Android"

Anyway, please provide more details like Activity class code, preview screen as well as your phone screen to get better help from everyone

I have checked Activity class code and also the TextView I set to be displayed, all are correct, but my phone still displays "Hello Android!"

Can you share your Activity class and Phone screen when running?
